# Give Proper Space between two sql value in Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, drop-down-menu, whitespace

I have Dropdownlist in my page, which the value combined from two field in my sql, here's the code :

```
   <td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dropFix" AppendDataBoundItems="true" EnableViewState="false runat="server"  DataSourceID="Fix" DataTextField="val" DataValueField="Value2">
        <Items>
          <asp:ListItem Text="None" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        </Items>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Fix" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DispatchConnectionString %>"
      SelectCommand="SELECT REPLACE((rtrim(value2) + space(len(value2)+3) + Value3),' ','&nbsp;') as val,Value2 FROM [Parameter] WHERE ([ParamType] = @paramtype) ORDER  BY dbo.fn_KeepNumInt(Value2)">
         <SelectParameters>
             <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="FIX" Name="ParamType" Type="String" />
         </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

so the text field to display in asp is :

```
REPLACE((rtrim(value2) + space(len(value2)+3) + Value3),' ','&nbsp;') as val
```

and unfortunately it's give me the result like this :

[image]

the spaces in display not properly, is it possible to give proper space between two value?

Comment: A low-rent, quick "solution" to this is to use a fixed-width font. If you want it to look *good* though, you might want to either modify your format or avoid the asp dropdownlist.

Comment: yes Fixed-width font to make sure the width are all the same

Comment: Humm just curious, right now the issu come up again, I already set the fixed with font , at first the display came right but again today, it scrambled

Comment: You'd have to show your html and CSS to have any reasonable guess as to what's happening.